# jQuery when(...).done(a, b, c) without unwrapping results

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am using `when()` to combine promises. I am looking for a method that will work like `done()` on that
combined promise, with these traits:

- only call the callback if all of the promises resolved (were not rejected / errored)
- send me the results passed to `resolveWith` for each promise in the combination, in order, but unwrapped - as opposed to `[result, "success", ...]` arrays for each resolution

Does something like this exist?

Comment: By "*send … in order … for each resolution*" I assume you mean to call the callback multiple times?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does something like this exist?

No, but you can write it yourself by using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function whenAllThenEach(promises, callback) {
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        return $.map(arguments, function(args) {
            return callback.apply(null, args);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
$.when(something1, something2).then(thenyoudosomething).done(function(){
      // the results from what you use .then
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called .then. You can use .then to process the arguments and return a new deferred that is resolved with arguments however you see fit.

```
function ajax(n) {
    return $.Deferred(function(def){
        def.resolve(n,"success",{responseText:n});
    }).promise();
}

$.when(ajax(1),ajax(2),ajax(3)).then(function(a,b,c){
    return $.Deferred().resolve(a[0],b[0],c[0]);
}).done(function(a,b,c){
    console.log(a,b,c); // 1 2 3
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rn3e/1/

Comment: But this sort of defeats the point since I still have to unpack the results of `a`, `b` and `c`...

Comment: That is correct. Unless, this is hidden behind another function(which is where it becomes very useful). Otherwise, no it isn't possible.

Comment: jQuery doesn't automatically do this because it would destroy information. Rather than assuming all you want is the response, it gives you the response, the status text, and the xhr. There is no way change this other than processing the arguments or extending jquery.